# pakage .json file cannot add android platform

Tags: ionic4

I cannot able to add android platform in package.json file after installing firebase cloud messaging.

```
"platforms": [

    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not very clear what you're saying but the way to add the android platform is to use the Ionic CLI.

You have options to use Cordova or Capacitor.

If you are just starting out it's probably best to use Cordova.

You type this into the command line:

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

The documentation for this command is here:

[ionic cordova platform - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-platform)

This will update the json files for you and add all the required configuration.

You should review the documentation though if this is your first time as there are many steps before this to configure your machine:

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/environment
- https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/android
- https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/android

Comment: no worries, if it helped you consider upvoting / marking as answer